# Clang won't complain about [id respondsToSelector:@selector(foo)];

Tags: static, clang

```
- (void)foo {
    id objc = nil;
    [objc respondsToSelector:@selector(foo)]; // Works fine
}
```

And

```
@protocol DummyProtocol
@end

//...

- (void)foo {
    id<DummyProtocol> objc = nil;
    [objc respondsToSelector:@selector(foo)]; //Error: No known instance method for selector 'respondsToSelector'
}
```

I know in this case DummyProtocol doesn't inherit from NSObject, therefor the error occurs. But the first case is kind of tricky, id is essentially a C struct pointer which point to a objc_object struct. It shouldn't  suppose to have any ObjC method implementation...

And the dot syntax will generate error in both cases, like

```
- (void)foo {
    id obj = nil;
    obj.description; //Error: Property 'description' not found on object of type '__strong id

    id<DummyProtocol> objc = nil;
    objc.description; //Error: Property 'description' not found on object of type '__strong id<DummyProtocol>'
}
```

I've check the [Clang documentations](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) with not luck. This has been in my head for about 2days, any suggestions will help...

Comment: You could eventually make DummyProtocol inherit from NSObject, using `@protocol DummyProtocol <NSObject>`, and that would allow you to `respondsToSelector:` safely. Or you could work with `NSObject<DummyProtocol> *objc = nil;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `id` with `[]` syntax will accept any selector from any class/protocol of your project at compilation
- `id<DummyProtocol>` will only accept selectors from DummyProtocol
- `.` syntax will only accept selectors from a specific concrete class/protocol (so it will never work with `id` alone)

Note that `description` isn't part of your DummyProtocol.